# wordpress user_admin_menu not firing

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to add a menu item to my user admin menu.

Here is the code I am using:( I have put it in my functions.php script)

```
add_action('user_admin_menu', 'ang_profile_actions');

function ang_profile_actions() { 
    add_users_page( 'test menu', 'test menu', 'exists', 'test_menu', 'ang_parse_profile_menu');
}
```

However, it appears 'user_admin_menu' is not firing. I tested this by adding an exit() in the function ang_profile_actions, and the page loaded with out stopping.

Is this set-up right? Am I even using the correct hook. There are so many it can be difficult to tell some times.

I just want to add menu items in the user profile page when they go to the 'wp-admin/profile.php' page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use when I need to do that:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'nb_users_submenu');

function nb_users_submenu() {
add_users_page('Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'read', 'page-slug', 'nb_display_page');
}
```

You can change read to any capabilities found at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Also note that nb_display_page is the function I use for displaying the content of the page.

Comment: Thanks. However, won't this also add the same menu item to the admin menu, not just the user admin menu?

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and it does NOT add the menu in the regular admin. I see now you used the function 'add_users_page'.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('user_admin_menu', 'ang_profile_actions');
```

won't work because it fires only when using multisite and will fire only when accessing .../wp-admin/user. Take a look inside .../wp-admin/user/admin.php there is the definition of constant WP_USER_ADMIN which is required to be true to fire 'user_admin_menu' action. If you'll try to access .../wp-admin/user using single site mode you'll be redirected to admin_url() where .../wp-admin/user/admin.php isn't being included so constant WP_USER_ADMIN isn't being defined and action 'user_admin_menu' doesn't fire.